# UIPinchGestureRecognizer not detected

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

When I pinch my view it does not respond until I place my view within the center of the screen by using **Horizontally in Container** and **Vertically in Container** constraints. When I use mentioned constraints it starts working perfectly.

Comment: when i place the view at any where else the pinch gesture stops working

Comment: The issue because of your contraints breaks.

Comment: But i have another view without constraints and upon which i am using pan and pinch gesture, so at run time when i place the view at the center,  the pinch gesture works and if drag and drop any where else the pinch gesture does not respond.